# Issue rendering PDF with AWS S3 url

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, react-pdf

I've a NextJS v14 project connected to AWS Amplify, in which, among other things, there are stored multiple PDFs. Now, what I would like to do is to simply display them using the `<Document />` component (of the `react-pdf` lib), but somehow I always get the error:

```
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I've tried multiple variants - following [these different AWS methods](https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/storage/download/) in order to retrieve the PDFs - but with no luck so far. For example:

```
// This returns a signed URL
const url = (await getUrl({ key: id })).url.toString();

// Other stuff...

return (
   <>
      <Document file={url}></Document>
   </>
)
```

I've also tried to convert the [PDF's blob](https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/storage/download/#get-the-text-value-of-downloaded-file) to Uint8Array and then pass it to the component like so: `<Document file={{ data: pdfUint8Array }}/>` but even this didn't work.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

---

I don't know if it helps, but so far I've managed to render the PDFs using the standard html `<object />` tag like so:

```
// The response have a content type of `application/octet-stream`
const { body, size } = await downloadData({key: id}).result;
// So, I explicitly convert it to `application/pdf`
const responseBlob = new Blob([await body.blob()], {type: "application/pdf"});
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(responseBlob);

// Other stuff...

return (
   <>
      <object
         data={blobUrl}
         type="application/pdf">
            <p>Not able to display the PDF. Please, download it.</p>
      </object>
   </>
)
```

But I would really like to achieve the same solution with the `<Document />` component.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add **raw-loader** webpack to your `next.config` file
like this example code

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.node/,
      use: 'raw-loader',
    })

    return config
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'yourBucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
      }
    ],
  },
  reactStrictMode: true
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

hope this help you